# If chown can change groups, why was chgrp created?

Tags: history, chown

So there's `chown` which lets you change the owner and group of files and/or directories. But there's also `chgrp` which only changes the group. Why was `chgrp` created? Isn't it redundant?

Comment: You can refer to the link here for more information. http://serverfault.com/questions/462174/using-chown-to-change-the-group-owner-of-a-directory-is-not-permitted-why/462180#462180

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`chown` initially couldn't set the group. Later, some implementations added it as `chown user.group`, some as `chown user:group` until it was eventually [standardised](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html) (emphasis mine):

> The 4.3 BSD method of specifying ***both owner and group*** was included in
> this volume of POSIX.1-2008 because:
>
> There are cases where the desired end condition could not be achieved
> using the chgrp and chown (that only changed the user ID) utilities.
> (If the current owner is not a member of the desired group and the
> desired owner is not a member of the current group, the chown()
> function could fail unless both owner and group are changed at the
> same time.)
>
> Even if they could be changed independently, in cases where both are
> being changed, there is a 100% performance penalty caused by being
> forced to invoke both utilities.

Even now:

- `chown :group` to only change the group is not portable or standard.
- `chown user:` to assign the primary group of the `user` in the user database is not standard either.

Comment: @dayuloli, thanks for the edit, but I didn't include that section of the spec because [I don't understand it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137086/22565)

Comment: Good question! Upvoted!

Comment: Nice to see that :group ans user: have been mentioned as non-standard. Many people here only check what their local vendor does and this is not helpful in a generic UNIX portal.

Answer (score 1):

Root privileges are required when changing the user-owner* of a file.

A regular user can change the group-owner of a file to another group that he/she is a member of.

Maybe from this privilege perspective it made sense to keep them separate, especially in the pre-sudo era. Like `chown` could have been made `setuid` with a group of 'admin', allowing members of the 'admin' group to change the user-owner of files.

*  I use "user-owner" and "group-owner" and "others" for consistency with ugo. Confusing "o" for "owner" is a common mistake.