# How to perform chown and chgrp in one command

Tags: linux, command-line, files, chown, chgrp

In order to change both a file's owner and group we can do this:

```
chown trump file
chgrp trump file
```

but can I do both commands in one approach or one command?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

per chown [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) `chown user:group file`:

```
chown trump:trump file
```

Comment: Or `chown trump: file` if `trump` is the primary group of user `trump`

Comment: Or `chown user.group filename` or `chown .group filename`

Comment: POSIX specifies allowed characters for user and group names. (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_278) The BSD `chown` manual states "Previous versions of the chown utility used the dot (`.`) character to distinguish the group name. This has been changed to be a colon (`:`) character, so that user and group names may contain the dot character." The RHEL man page for `chown` does not have that usage note. Nonetheless, there are reasons to abstain from using the `.` character.

Comment: Be careful what `username:` and `:groupname` are **not** standards - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136989/383045